# Wordpress - After manually updating mysql table in phpmyadmin for wordpress, the live post reflects the changes, but the post editor does not

Tags: mysql, wordpress, text-editor

Every year we update our posts with new data. For example, the best places to live in 2018.

I am trying to write a python script this year that updates the post_content in mysql so we don't have to do a bunch of copying and pasting into the html post editor.

However, as a test, I manually updated wp_post in phpmyadmin for one article. After updating, the following happens:

1. The mysql table correctly updates. I can export the table with the changes and they are all in there.
2. The LIVE article is updated.
3. However, when I go to edit the article in wordpress's post editor, it's still showing the previous version.
4. Therefore, if I save the post in post editor, it will revert back to the old version.

I am completely out of ideas. I've been googling for hours and no one seems to 
have this problem.

More background on my setup:

- Wordpress version 4.9.1
- Using dreampress from dreamhost as the host

Here's a link to the working page:
https://www.homesnacks.net/best-places-to-live-in-georgia-122131/

Comment: Do it properly, and write a script that uses `wp_update_post`, instead of fiddling with database contents directly ...

Comment: If you *must* horse around with your WordPress database directly, first use a database cleanup plugin that deletes drafts and old versions from your `wp_posts` table. That way your direct update procedure is more likely to hit the correct row. And, by the way, back up your installation before you do this kind of stuff.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the tips! Since my code is in python, I'm gonna play with using the wordpress api and the post endpoint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up hooking into the wordpress API:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

And these tutorials helped

- https://www.cloudways.com/blog/setup-and-use-oauth-authentication-using-wp-rest-api/
- https://discussion.dreamhost.com/t/authenticating-to-the-wordpress-api-using-oauth-1-0a-server/65094